# Add values from lists of same length in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, tuples

**I want to add each value of two (maybe more for expand-ability) lists or tuples and return another iterable with the sums of the corresponding values.**

Here are two lists filled with arbitrary values.

```
l1 = [90, 7, 30, 6]
l2 = [8,  2, 40, 5]
```

Of course, adding them with a plus operator simply concatenates.

```
l1 + l2 = [90, 7, 30, 6, 8, 2, 40, 5]
```

Is there a simple way, other than iterating through it, to add each value to the matching one of a corresponding list or tuple?

```
l1 + l2 = [98, 9, 70, 11]
```

That's what I need, and I really think **there must be a simpler way than making an iteration function** to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `zip`:

```
l1 = [90, 7, 30, 6]
l2 = [8,  2, 40, 5]

new = [a+b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Output:

```
[98, 9, 70, 11]
```